# Progressbar not updating in thread android

Tags: android, progress-bar, download

when I download file i want progressbar sync with this. but not, my code is:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                        //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                        fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                        //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                        downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                        pbar.setProgress((downloadedSize/totalSize)*100);
                        pbar.refreshDrawableState();

                        Log.d("CURRENT:", "" + (downloadedSize/totalSize)*100);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
```

Also my catlog file is not updated. Any help please....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update the UI from a background thread, Use `AsyncTask` because Androiders call it [painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

[Here is a nice Tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/11/progressbar-running-in-asynctask.html) for using `ProgressBar` using `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 1):

No need of AsyncTask, in your thread use `MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread()`. Would do the same job as AsyncTask, but it cuts you time on recoding all the stuff. :) Cheers